# Use JQuery to keep active sub-navigation open when loading a new page

Tags: jquery

I have built a sidebar navigation that collapses & expands when the nav titles are clicked. this all works great. however, if i expand / open one of the nav groups and click to go to a page, when the new page loads all the nav groups start out closed again. I would love to find a way for the active nav group to stay open.

Here is what I've used for the collapse / expand:
(it's currently set up so that only one of the nav groups will be open at a time)

```
/* Collapse and Expand */
$(".slideTitle").click(function() {
    $(".indexListOpen").removeClass("indexListOpen").addClass("indexList");
    $(this).next().toggleClass("indexList").toggleClass("indexListOpen");
});
```

And this is what I was trying to use to keep the current nav group open when the new page loads:

```
/* keep current nav group open */
var path = location.pathname;
$('.indexListOpen a[@href$="' + path + '"]').addClass("selected");
$(".selected").parent().parent().removeClass("indexList").addClass("indexListOpen");
```

Not working ... so I'm sure I'm doing plenty wrong.
The page I am working on is located at instarservices.com/commercial

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dcneiner said the `@` has been deprecated in the latest version of jQuery. But it looks like you are targeting a `indexListOpen` that doesn't exist on a fresh page load. So either remove that or change it to `indexList` and it should work

```
$('a[href$="' + path + '"]').addClass("selected");
```

or

```
$('.indexList a[href$="' + path + '"]').addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery 1.3 or newer (point version), the attribute selectors cannot be called with the `@` symbol. Additionally the presence of the starting slash may be causing problems. So I would recommend doing this:

```
var path = location.pathname.replace(/(^\/)/g,''); // Removes the opening slash if present
$('.indexListOpen a[href$=' + path + ']').addClass("selected");
```

If you run into browser differences (works in some, not in another) then check three things:

1. You may need to escape the `/` character before using it in the jQuery selector
2. You may be getting a trailing slash in the `pathname` that is not present at the end of your selectors
3. On most Windows servers, url's are not case sensitive. You will want to add `.toLowerCase()` to the end of the `path = location ...` statement and make sure your `href` attributes are all lower case.

Good luck, and if these suggestions don't work, try posting your HTML for your navigation to help us troubleshoot it further.

Comment: Huge help!! Thanks so much! I didn't realize the @ symbol was deprecated. I will look into your other tips too!