# Persistent URLs with a jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a simple jQuery slider for my website, and I was wondering if it's possible to assign a URL for each pane.

For example /index.html#about will slide to the about tab by default.

Many thanks for your help and responses.

Comment: You could check out how this SO user is doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800541/use-jquery-to-keep-active-sub-navigation-open-when-loading-a-new-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try extending this:

http://www.stilbuero.de/jquery/history/

Comment: I think that's what I've been looking for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done programatically in JavaScript (with jQuery). You should parse the page URL (from document.location), extract everything after "#" and use this data to initialize your slider.